# SSH tunnel is up, but cannot connect to database

Tags: ssh, database, ssh-tunnel

I am working on a project where we are using an SSH Tunnel with port forwarding. Our server contains a website which references a database on our customers server. We have established an SSH connection as illustrated by the below netstat:

```
tomcat@ServerName:~$ netstat -an | grep 24012
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:24012         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:24012               :::*                    LISTEN
```

The problem is that whenever we go to login to the website (involves querying the database) we cannot get a connection. From that I am assuming the connection is up but the database will not allow access. Can anyone give me some guidance as to how i can troubleshoot this issue. Am I mistaken in thinking the SSH tunnel is up just because it is listed on netstat? Our ssh tunnel is as follows minus a few details:

```
echo y | plink.exe -ssh -R 24011:localhost:1433 connect@testsite1.fern.io -pw passwordhere
```

Comment: How is the SSH tunnel being used?

Comment: @Jenny D Could you explain your question? I added the code for the SSH tunnel if that helps. The tunnel is used to connect a site on our server with the database on their server.

Comment: You've shown how you set it up, but not how you use it - through a script of your own, through some option within your webserver config, through an existing client...? Also, "cannot get a connection" is insufficiently specific. Do you get a timeout, do you get connection refused, do you get a connection but can't login - what?